# How to change the value of a variable in shell script with the output of command everytime script is being run by cronjob?

Tags: shell-script

I have a script running a get command and store the output in a variable called `newvalue` and one more variable called `oldvalue` (manually stored some value in it). Then script subtract `newvalue - oldvalue` and store the result in a variable called `finalvalue` and echo's final value. I have to run this script using cron job every 4 hour and send email containing echo of `finalvalue`. Till here everything is working fine. Now i want this script to update the `oldvalue` variable with value of `newvalue` once its done sending the email. Means every 4 hour when script run, it should change the value of variable `oldvalue` with last `newvalue`. Please suggest the workaround.

Comment: Show the scripts, what do you expect as result and so on.

Answer (score 4):

When you run a script, no matter if you run it from `cron` or directly in the command line, that script runs in its own "subshell", in its own environment. Any variables set during the script's execution are only visible to *that* script while it runs. If you then run the same script again, it is completely independent of the first run and there is no way for a variable from the first execution to somehow survive and be picked up by the second, separate execution.

Therefore, if you need to keep a value across different instances of the script, you are going to have to use a temporary file to store it. Just add something like this to your script:

```
oldValue=$(cat /path/to/temp/file);
newValue=$(whatever gives you the new value)
finalValue=$((newvalue - oldvalue))
echo "$finalValue" > /path/to/temp/file
```